# How is value type array allocated in a heap?

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, heap-memory, value-type

I read the answer to some of the similar questions but my question is little different due to fact that I do not understand a statement written about this in a book.

> Because a struct is a value type, each instance does not require
>   instantiation of an object on the heap; this incurs a useful savings
>   when creating many instances of a type. For instance, creating an
>   array of value type requires only a single heap allocation.

I mean How can array require only a single heap allocation?... or what does it mean by single heap allocation

Comment: What specifically don't you understand in that statement?

Comment: An array is just a block of memory on the heap.  If it contains a value type then that's what's in that block of memory.  If it has reference types then those point at objects else where in the heap.

Comment: I mean How can array require only a single heap allocation?... or what does it mean by single heap allocation

Comment: A "single hep allocation" means a single contiguous block of memory on the heap.

Comment: are you familiar with C or C++ ?

Comment: The idea that "Value types go on the stack and reference types go on the heap" is wrong. *Sometimes* value types are allocated on the stack. But there are plenty of times that they're not. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How can array require only a single heap allocation?... or what does it mean by single heap allocation

First of all, let's clarify what we mean by "heap" vs "stack".

Most programming environments today are stack-based. As you run a program, each time you call a method a new entry is pushed onto a special stack provided for your program. This stack entry (or frame) tells the system where to look for the method's executable code, what arguments were passed, and exactly where to return to in the calling code after the method exits. When a method finishes, it's entry is removed (popped) from the stack, so the program can go back to the previous method. When the stack is empty, the program has finished.<sup>1</sup> There is often support for this special stack directly in the CPU.

The memory for the stack is allocated when the program is first launched, which means the stack itself has a fixed (limited) size. This is where "Stack Overflows" come from; get too deep down too many method calls, and the stack will run out of space. Each frame on the stack also has a certain amount of space for local variables for the method, and this is the memory we're talking about when we say value types live on the stack. The local variables stored on the stack do not require new allocations; the memory is *already there*. Just remember: this only applies in the context of local variables in a method.

The heap, on the other hand, is memory not automatically granted to the program. It is memory the program must request above and beyond it's core allocation. Heap memory has to be managed more carefully (so it doesn't leak — but we have a garbage collector to help with this), but there is (usually) much more of it available. Because it has to be granted by the operating system on request, initial allocations for the heap are also a little slower than memory used from the stack.<sup>2</sup> For reference types, you can think of the `new` keyword as requesting a new heap memory allocation.

As a *broad generalization*, we say reference types are allocated on the heap, and value types are allocated on the stack (though there are plenty of exceptions for this<sup>3</sup>).

---

Now we understand this much, we can start to look at how .Net handles arrays.

*The core array type itself is a reference type.* What I mean is, for any given type `T`, the `T` may (or may not) be a value type, but an array of `T` (`T[]`) is *always* a reference type. In the "stack vs heap" context, this means creating a new array is a heap allocation, even if `T` is a value type. Arrays in .Net also have a fixed size<sup>4</sup>.

An additional attribute of value types is they also have a known/fixed size, based on the members. Therefore, an array of value types has a fixed number of elements, each with a known fixed size. That's enough information so allocating a new array of value types will get all the space for the array object *and it's elements* in single heap allocation. The *value* of each item (not just a reference) is held right there with the array's core memory. Now we have a bunch of value-type objects, but their memory is on the heap, rather than the stack.

This can be further complicated by a value type with one or more reference type members. In this situation, the space for the value type is allocated as normal, but the the part of the value for the reference members is just a reference. It still requires separate allocations or assignments to populate those reference members.

For an array holding reference types, the initial heap allocation for the array still allocates space for all the elements, but space reserved for each element is *only enough for the reference*. That is, initially each element in the array is still `null`. To populate the array you must still set those references to objects in memory, either by assigning existing objects or allocating new ones.

Finally, just as we were able to use arrays to get a value-type onto the heap, instead of the stack, there are also ways to force reference types to [allocate from the stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/stackalloc). However, generally you *should not do this* unless you really understand the full implications.

---

<sup>1) There are different conventions on exactly when a frame is pushed/popped for each method call, depending on the platform, compiler configuration, and more, so only look at this paragraph for the general idea; the exact specifics will be incorrect in some particulars on any given platform.</sup>

<sup>2) For future reading, it is also useful to understand how programs handle *addressing* for heap memory.</sup>

<sup>3) Eric Lippert has [an excellent write-up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/the-truth-about-value-types) of this topic.</sup>

<sup>4) That is, arrays in .Net they are *true arrays* in the full formal computer science sense, unlike the associative array-like collection types in many other platforms. .Net has these, too, but it calls them what they are: collections rather than arrays.</sup>

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. If someone believe my understanding of these concepts is flawed, I'd love to correct it.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter. Although I like your answer, I suggest you add a link to Eric Lippert's blog about value types vs reference types where you say "though there are plenty of exceptions for this." https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types/

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn Thanks a lot for your answer. Such a thorough explanation. I got what you are explaining.

Comment: @Jim Mischel, thanks for the link, will go through it as well.

Comment: Well detailed explanation. Seems pretty good for me :)

Answer (score 4):

An array is itself a reference type, which means, it is allocated on the managed heap. But if it is an array of a value type, it reserves the the memory needed for its size in one single step. Lets you have a struct with 4 Int32 in it.

```
A struct4Int[1000] will allocate 16000 bytes in one step.
```

An array of a reference type will take only the memory needed for the referencing (32bit or 64bit per item, depending on the architecture you are compiling for). Lets say a class with 4Int32 in it.

```
A class4Int[1000] will allocate 4000 or 8000 bytes at first.
```

The items are filled with the address of the references, which is intially null.

After creating the array you will have to allocate memory for every instance of the reference type and putting it's reference into the array (multiple allocations on the heap), adding another 16000 bytes on the heap in 1000 small pieces.